# Addressof operator returns invalid address in embedded environment

Tags: c++

When debugging a segfault error in a cross compiled embedded linux environment, I isolated the problem to be a call of memset.

Further investigation showed, that there is something strange going on. I tried to run a test application on the target with the following code:

```
string st;
st = "teststring";
std::cout << "address: " << &st << std::endl;
std::cout << "sizeof: " << sizeof(st) << std::endl;
std::cout << "value (before): " << st << std::endl;
memset(&st,0,sizeof(st));
std::cout << "value (after): " << st << std::endl;
```

The application exits with a segfault on the memset line. The output is:

```
address: 0xbed7fb4c
sizeof: 4
value (before): teststring
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Application finished with exit code 139.
```

The same code compiled and run on the desktop environment produces the following output:

```
address: 0x7ffdc172f7a0
sizeof: 32
value (before): teststring
value (after):
```

Why does the identical code behave differently on the desktop and on the embedded system?

Both are Qt applications without using QT components. The compiler is GCC for the desktop and buildroot gcc for the embedded system.

Memset itself is not the problem here (as indicated by the different sizeof result). The following code also produces a segfault on the embedded system:

```
string st;
st = "teststring";
char* p = (char*)&st;
for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(st); ++i) {
        p[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(st)` doesn't tell you how many characters there are in the string, `st.length()` does.

Comment: `Memset itself is not the problem here` - yes it is, and it's very unclear why you think the difference in size indicates that there isn't. Both your code snippets are undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) requires the the object you pass to it be trivially-copyable.  `std::string` is not trivially-copyable so it is **undefined behavior** to call `memset` on it.

If you want to clear the contents of the `string` then you should call [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) on the instance.

Your second example is also illegal as you are breaking the strict aliasing rules.  a `std::string` is not a c-string.  You cannot treat the address of the string object as the first character in the underlying c-string.  For all you know the size of the string is stored first in the class and you are overwrite that with garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to perform illegal operations.

To use [`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) on an object, it must be an aggregate. [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) isn't one. If you want to fill it with zeros, use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill). If you just want to make it empty, use [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear).

If you really, really want to access the string as a character array, you can say

```
char* p = &st[0];
for (size_t i = 0; i != st.size(); ++i) {
        p[i] = 0;
}
```

`&st[0]` yields address of the first character and string guarantees contiguous memory layout of the data.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers given, if you want to make sure you don't create programs that do things like this (like calling `memset`) use type traits and [std::is_trivially_copyyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<std::string>(), 
                 "Sorry, you're memset is not going to work");
}
```

Now the program will not compile, let alone run, due to the type given `std::is_trivially_copyable` failing the static_assert.

Compare to this:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo
{
    char x[10];
};

int main()
{
   static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<foo>(), 
                 "Sorry, you're memset is not going to work");
}
```

This compiles with no errors, since `foo` is trivially copyable.  The type_traits are your friend here.